# Geometric mean of parallel sides of a trapezium

Tags: geometry

Parallel sides of a trapezium are $p,q$ long.

How to construct using ruler& compass a middle line length $\sqrt{p q}$ parallel to $p,q$  between points on slanting sides?

Comment: Let $MN=\sqrt{pq}$. Then $MBCN \sim AMND$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\square ABCD$ have parallel sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ of lengths $p$ and $q$, respectively, with $p > q$. We seek points $M$ and $N$ on $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ such that $|\overline{MN}|^2 = p q$.

If we define 
$$k := \frac{|\overline{AM}|}{|\overline{MD}|} = \frac{|\overline{BN}|}{|\overline{NC}|}$$
it's not hard to prove that 
$$k = \frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{q}}$$

This illustration shows a construction:

[image]

Here, we've used the standard semi-circle construction to construct $\sqrt{p}$ as the geometric mean of $1$ and $p$; and $\sqrt{q}$ as the geometric mean of $1$ and $q$. A segment of length $\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}$ is constructed, and the corresponding ratio $k$ is transferred to $\overline{AD}$, giving $M$ and then $N$. $\square$